# Google Play API Allows Background Location Updates?

Tags: java, android, google-play-services

Someone told me it was a good idea to use the `Google Play API` to handle location updates. I am needing to receive very frequent location updates in order to return the users distance.

**If this is a good idea, does anyone know if it allows updates in the background? Meaning, when a user leaves the app? Is it even a good idea to use this API?**

I couldn't find anything about this in its docs.

Comment: I would say yes. If you are dealing with geofencing then I highly recommend you read this (http://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html).

Comment: And this http://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html

Comment: No, I am not using geofencing. I am just needing quite frequent location updates to track the users distance.